# creating custom tabs in angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, tabs

How do we implement or any idea how to create custom tabs for example on the example image below guys ? for example the general , security role and sso and password and login are tabs. If i click the general tab it will show the general card on the right side , if I click security role and sso it will show the security role and sso card like it will scroll on the top and it will ne on the position of the general card. Any idea with these guys ? Thank you .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-flsnue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only "play" with `[fxFlexOrder]`

If you defined an array like

```
order=[0,1,2]
```

each fxFlex can be like

```
//use order[0] and sortOrder(0) for the first div
//    order[1] and sortOrder(1) for the second one
//    ...
<div fxFlex [fxFlexOrder]="order[0]" (click)="sortOrder(0)">
..
</div>
```

The function sortOrder change the array and scroll the window to top

```
  sortOrder(index) {
    const value=this.order[index]
    if (value != 0) {
      this.order = this.order.map(
        (x, i) => (x = i == index ? 0 : x < value ? x + 1 : x)
      );
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-5izndv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the changes

Comment: I tried clicking and testing the stackblitz with your changes Sir but it does not seem to work..

Comment: it does not respond when I click it

Comment: can we have the trigger on the left side Sir ? https://imgur.com/a/egisBgK .. For example if I click the general tab on the left side then it show and scroll the card on the right side, right now sir on your code the click was on the right side

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9UjwLLM why is that my layout is destroyed when I use fxFlex ?

Comment: this is my original layout but when I use the flex https://imgur.com/a/1sbJ6Om , it is destroyed like the https://imgur.com/a/9UjwLLM

Comment: @TimLaunders, If you open in a new window, when you click in one of the element to the right, this element pass to the top position. I understood that this is what are you looking for :(

Comment: is it possible to add some animation bro ?

Comment: @TimLaunders, "imposible is nothing". I write another answer, but in this case I don't use mat-flex else use divs with position absolute and a "manual animation". Really I should think about using animation and mat-flex, but I'm in hurry (as always) I hope this give you any clue.

Answer (score 0):

There're another aproach taht not use mat-flex else div with position absolute and manual animation.

Imagine an html like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <mat-card class="custom">
            {{order|json}}
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div #card (click)="sortOrder(0)">
            <mat-card class="custom2">
                custom 0
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div #card (click)="sortOrder(1)">
            <mat-card class="custom2">
                custom 1
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div #card (click)="sortOrder(2)">
            <mat-card class="custom2">
                custom 2
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a .css like

```
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.column{
  margin-left:15px;
}
.column>div
{
  position:absolute;
}
```

The idea is create a manual animation. For this, we get using `@ViewChildren` the  "cards" and inject in constructor [AnimationBuilder](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder)

```
  timing = '500ms ease-in-out';
  initPos=0;
  @ViewChildren('card', { read: ElementRef }) items: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  private player: AnimationPlayer;
  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) {}
```

Our function "animate" received a nativeElement and a top and create an animation to move the nativeElement. Also I want pass another parameter last to allow me execute an action when the animation finished if the parameter is true

```
  animate(element: any, top: string | number,last:boolean) {
    const myAnimation = this.builder.build([
      animate(this.timing, style({ top: top}))
    ]);
    this.player = myAnimation.create(element);
    if (last)
    {
      this.player.onDone(()=>{
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      })
    }
    this.player.play();
  }
```

So the only is calculate the position "top" acording an array order that we change when click

```
  sortOrder(index: number) {
    const value = this.order[index];
    if (value != 0) {
      this.order = this.order.map(
        (x, i) => (x = i == index ? 0 : x < value ? x + 1 : x)
      );
      
    }
    let pos = this.initPos ||0;
    for (let i=0;i<this.order.length;i++)
    {
      const index=this.order.findIndex(x=>x==i);
      const card = this.items.find((_, j) => j == index);
      if (card) {
        this.animate(card.nativeElement, pos ? pos + 'px' : 0,i==this.order.length-1);
        pos += card.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      }

    }
  }
```

Finally, don't forget in ngAfterViewInit call to the function sortOrder

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.initPos=this.items.first.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    this.sortOrder(0)
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdxmbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-overview-example.ts)

Comment: do you have implementation like this one with the latest anagular Sir ? I tried it on my latest project it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: the stackblitz is about Angular 12, but I'm prety sure that also work in Angular 10 (the animation have no changes)